# This path for a picture doesn't work

Tags: php, apache

I'm building graphs using pChart in PHP. The case is that I have my picture in the right folder, I know it because if I put that path in the browser I can see my picture, but in the template, it doesn't show up. Firebug shows "failed to load the given URI".

```
<img src="/home/user1/mysite/Admin/Template/mx_graphs/example13.png">
```

The picture has all the **rw permissions** given, and the folder.

Comment: The rest of the world cannot normally read your complete hard disc drive. I suppose you've set up a web site and you only provide access to a small directory tree that's mapped as `/` in the URL.

Comment: nono, im working in local

Comment: Why the Apache tag then?

Comment: Browser understand your address like `http://localhost/home/user1/mysite/Admin/Template/mx_graphs/example13.png` open that path and you will see same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the statement:

```
<img src="/home/user1/mysite/Admin/Template/mx_graphs/example13.png">
```

Will run on the client side, so if you run this on the very computer where the picture is stored, it should work fine, but if you try to open it from another computer it will not work.
Try to use relative path (http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/), and try to keep the website resources into the website root folder, so that even when you host the site the image be copied over and will still be accessible..

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be using a UNIX file path instead of a relative URI. Your web server is unlikely to be configured to have the DocumentRoot be `/` (and it would be very silly to do so).

Construct a URI relative either to the HTML document or to the DocumentRoot of your server.

The latter will *probably* be `/Admin/Template/mx_graphs/example13.png`